# Netcat:use a script to test ports are open from a given source-host to remote-host using netcat

Tags: linux, bash, shell, netcat

I am trying to use a script to test ports are open from a given source-host to remote-host using netcat

So from a bastion, get the script to ssh to  a source and from that source-host nc -v remote-host 1521
Ideally i will want to test from the source-host to multiple destinations
As an example:

## /bin/bash

kinit # prompt for my creds

ssh source-host nc -v -n remote-host 1521

When I run script it will prompt for creds and then get error:

nc: gettaddrinfo: Name or service no known.

I suspect it is the -n flag but when I try without, it hangs

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong and how I can achieve in simplest way

Answer (score 0):

Use ip address for remote-host instead or something like:

```
ssh source-host nc -v -n `dig +short remote-host` 80
```

Comment: so you right if i try with ip I no longer get the getipaddr error but
get for example

ssh 10.1.1.1 nc -v -n 10.1.1.2 1521
enter password: 
and will time out with error nc: connect to 10.1.1.2 port 1521 failed
( i have verifed works when logged into 10.1.1.1 and run nc -v 10.1.1.2 1521)

Am wondering am i missing something with nc command ? as when i run for example

ssh 10.1.1.1 ping -c 3 10.1.1.2  it works